# Why are characters double in a sequence?

Tags: film-techniques, animation, disenchantment

In the first episode of *Disenchantment* (2018), during the wedding scene, right before Elfo interrupts the ceremony, there’s a look of the inside of the temple in which we can see all the guests and main characters:

[image: capture of disenchantment]

As you can see, most of the wedding guests are doubled. This happens only at this particular scene (not a single frame but a few seconds); at previous parts of the wedding we can see the guests from the same angle and no one is repeated:

[image: capture of disenchantment]

How does an issue like this happen? I thought the animation was done by computer and not the classic transparent sheets/cels.

Comment: This question would benefit from some hand drawn circles highlighting where the duplicates are.

Comment: Missing freehand circles

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the differnce between these two pictures, the first one has sharper lighting coming from the windows, and some of the characters are correctly lit by this light, others are not. So this is probably where some error in production happen, with the doubled characters being dark and light, meaning, their lighter version were meant to be moved only a bit, like in the guy in bottom right corner in a red shirt, to produce the effect of their fronts being lit by the light from the windows. With other characters, their "lit" version was moved too much.